# Argument of type '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, string, observable, angular13

***I have some code but get error with angular 13 string[]***

Argument of type '(string  | undefined)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.

In my product list compnent

```
        ngOnInit(): void {
            this._getPro();
            this._getCate();
        }
        private _getPro(categoriesFilter?: string[]) {
            this.proService.getProducts(categoriesFilter).subscribe((pros) => {
                this.products = pros;
            });
        }
        private _getCate() {
            this.catService.getCategories().subscribe((cate) => {
                this.categories = cate;
            });
        }
        categoryFilter() {
            const selectedCategories = this.categories
                .filter((cate) => cate.checked)
                .map((cate) => cate.id);
            this._getPro(selectedCategories);
        }
    }
```

***In my product service***

```
//get all


     getProducts(categoriesFilter?: string[]): Observable<Product[]> {
            let params = new HttpParams();
            if (categoriesFilter) {
                params = params.append('categories', categoriesFilter.join(','));
            }
            return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.apiURLProducts, { params: params });
        }
```

[this error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IlD2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another filter criterion to ensure that the `id` property is set on each category, and make the filter function a [type guard predicate function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsCBzA9gJxFAvFA3gWACgooBjACwlIGsIATAfgC4oAjFFAGwjgDsBuIiQCWjFgGdgaYbySDCAX3lE6VTnDTRSKXpLIJk6YRHEt4iVBgDaAXXmrS6zVABmAV16lgwnVAD6SBDAAApoKFAAFKQGlsamUJLSsrYAlCwAbiiiyoTunt6+0RboIABiwpyIaBEpeEJQAPQNZDp64hDcXvTmhtIm2FDA5MLiAHRFvXH12rrACR1UiHQ9sf04E6vi9SQkoy4VVRFRaWRQI4PgECgupwBkdcQ7TxRUtHQsUm4Q8k9PohJSGRybY7BTYAB8UAAQhxuHwouNKDR6FBbvdSKNRCkUiDdgBbOBgI64UQKWpYSFYn6NZpDEajAJBUIoCLtTpLFZGEwpamMkJhVkLLrLGJc8Q8ogKIhAA)

```ts
categoryFilter() {
  const selectedCategories = this.categories
      .filter((c): c is typeof c & {
        checked: true;
        id: string;
      } => Boolean(c.checked && c.id))
      .map(({id}) => id);
  this._getPro(selectedCategories);
}
```